# Trying Twilio whatsappp api call but getting error 20422

Tags: go, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am getting an error while using twilio whatsapp api.

Following is the code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/twilio/twilio-go"
    api "github.com/twilio/twilio-go/rest/api/v2010"
)

func main() {

    clientParameter := twilio.ClientParams{}
    clientParameter.Username = "AC***********************ba"
    clientParameter.Password = "ce************************27"
    clientParameter.AccountSid = "AC************************ba"

    client := twilio.NewRestClientWithParams(clientParameter)

    params := &api.CreateMessageParams{}
    params.SetContentSid("HT**********************70")
    params.SetMessagingServiceSid("MG******************************0d")
    params.SetFrom("whatsapp:+917*******2")
    params.SetTo("whatsapp:+917********4")

    resp, err := client.Api.CreateMessage(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        if resp.Sid != nil {
            fmt.Println(*resp.Sid)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(resp.Sid)
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is -

```
Status: 400 - ApiError 20422: Invalid Parameter (null) More info: https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20422
```

Same error I am getting if trying through Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error [20422](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20422#:%7E:text=The%20request%20contained%20malformed%20or,Invalid%20or%20missing%20XML%20data) means that one of these three conditions is not met:

- Lacking a specified Content-Type header field
- Invalid or missing XML data
- Invalid parameter type or value

> The error log in the console might provide a more detailed explaination.

Since you are using the SDK, it's most likely the third bullet point. Is there a reason why you are using a `MessagingServiceSid` and the `From` field? I'd recommend updating the client to the latest version and running this script:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/twilio/twilio-go"
    api "github.com/twilio/twilio-go/rest/api/v2010"
)


func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    client := twilio.NewRestClient()

    params := &api.CreateMessageParams{}
    params.SetTo("whatsapp:"+os.Getenv("RECIPIENT_PHONE_NUMBER"))
    params.SetFrom(os.Getenv("TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE"))
    params.SetContentSid(os.Getenv("CONTENT_SID"))

    _, err = client.Api.CreateMessage(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Message sent successfully!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have figured out the issue for above error, actually i was using the whatsapp template sid for the content sid. When I created a seprate template using content editor and used its id then it worked perfectly. Also I have a question that - what is the use of whatsapp templates when I need to create a template using content editor?? And one more question in the documentation it is given that service sid is required for both the provided method 1. where service sid is added in from field 2. where it is added in MessagingServiceSid field, is it even needed to form a service ??

Comment: Or can i just use contentId, from and to number?? When i do so i get error {
    "code": 21619,
    "message": "A text message body or media urls must be specified.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21619",
    "status": 400
}, and as i can not send direct message in body, because then new error is returns suggesting to use template , (as service messages are outside 24 hour window). Also I have one more question , is their any way to send message to multiple receivers in a single rest call? or do I have to make a rest call for each message? Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: I'm glad you could figure it out. I'd love to answer your questions but I'm afraid this will get too complicated in the comments section as there are not threaded comments and other users will have a hard time to find the questions with the appropriate answer. So I'd recommend opening new questions.

Comment: One questions fits into your original question: **Yes, you can use the messaging service sid as "from" **.  You can have both, as a messaging service can include multiple senders.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response!! as per your advice I am creating seprate questions ...please also have a look at this question regarding twilio ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301037/in-twilio-what-is-the-use-of-whatsapp-templates-option-provided-seprately