# Twilio's verified whatsapp sender's name does not appear in the chatlist, instead it shows the number

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

How can I set the whatsapp sender's name that will appear in chat list?

Currently, I am using my own number that is verified sender on twilio, with a specific name. When I send some message the name does not appear in the chat list, there it only shows the sender number. If I go into the profile details, then I am able to see the name set for the sender.

I was hoping that I could show the same name in the chat-list also.

Can anyone tell why is it happening and what can be the solution to this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you don't only need a verified Twilio sender but also send a [Business Verification Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/business-accounts/#official-business-account) direct from the Meta Business Manager:

[image: WA Business Manager]

Comment: Thank you for answering this question also IObert, could you also answer the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321344/using-twilio-conversations-for-receiving-and-responding-to-user-initiated-conver