# Using Twilio Conversations for receiving and responding to user-initiated conversations

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

1. I am a quite sure that, the number used in Whatsapp business api can not be used directly in whatsapp app or whatsapp business app, still can anyone confirm that??
2. If to receive and respond to the user Initiated message we need to form an UI interface, what are the possibilities and what is the best option to do so??

- One, I thought was created our own chat UI, which I think will be time consuming and complicated.
- Second, I am looking toward twilio's chat and conversation option. It is mentioned on twilio site that twilio-chats is depreciated. So I was looking forward to use twilio conversation.

But before going deep into twilio conversation apis and their documentation I would like to know if it will fit my use case.

**Need -**
Can I use twilio conversation such that, I can connect my verified sender to 3-4 separate whatsapp numbers to respond form their individual whatsapp or whatsapp-business app, to all the user initiated conversation.

If possible can I get some specific documentation or guidance for it??

Answer (score 1):

You are right, numbers used for the WhatsApp Business API cannot be used in the WhatsApp app.
More generally, you need to use a Twilio number you purchased in the Console as a WhatsApp sender. It won't work with your verified sender (which is probably your personal phone numbers, right?).

The [WhatsApp Sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox) offers you some capabilities to start your development with a POC. But you won't be able to use this prod use-cases.

Comment: I have just one question, If I am using twilio conversation, at a time I can only connect one private number(not the verified sender) to the a verified sender of twilio for single conversation SID(not for multiple conversation SID at same time), am I right??